# How can i print 'n' numbers in consecutive order in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need your help Senpai!

How can I print 'n' number of series in a consecutive order?

Basically, I want to print 'n' numbers in series without spaces.

For example in my code,

```
    for x in range(1, n+1):
        print(x)
```

Output for n=5

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

But i want to get output like:
12345 (without any spaces in a single line).

Help me with this please!

Comment: ```print(x, end="")```

Comment: `print(*range(1, n+1), sep="")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```py
n = 10
print(*range(1,n+1), sep="")
```

`print(*range(1,n+1))` is equivalent of `print(1, 2, ..., n)`
And you need `sep=""` so it print doesn't displayadditional new line characters between the numbers

Comment: upvoted, but still an explanation would have been nice

Comment: as mentioned in comments, you might not need `end=''`

Comment: Edited it accordingly

Comment: This worked for me, thanks a lot.